# Can't make rounded corners with bootstrap class for table

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap for table and can't make rounded borders.

For some reason, it doesn't make them table rounded. How I can fix that?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-bordered bg-white rounded">
  <thead class="mid-purple-bg rounded-top">
    <tr>
      <th class="col-lg-1 w-50">Code</th>
      <th class="col-lg-10">Name</th>
      <th class="col-lg-1 w-50">Plan</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="active-link" style="font-size: 16px;" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="">
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I found for this question.

```html
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container py-5">
      <div class="card">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead class="mid-purple-bg rounded-top">
              <tr>
                <th class="col-lg-1 w-50">Code</th>
                <th class="col-lg-10">Name</th>
                <th class="col-lg-1 w-50">Plan</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="active-link" style="font-size: 16px;" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="">
                <td>test</td>
                <td>test2</td>
                <td>test3</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be further improved by adding a short explanation of why this fixes OP's problem.

Comment: it works, but a thead that has class mid-purple-bg has just background color of purple and it doesn't see that the container is rounded. Why so ? thead has sharp corners.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with a table inside a div. I first tried giving the div a class of `rounded` but that didn't work.

At the end I found that the trick is to make the table borderless!

I.e. giving the table the classes `table-borderless rounded` does work.

I don't know if this is true for every version of bootstrap though.